# Update React State of Child Component based on Parent component AJAX call without defining(knowing) data structure of AJAX data

Tags: reactjs

I am unsure if I understand the canonical or a preferred way of architecting the data structure(s) of Parent/Child Components that share data.

?? Why do I have to declare the structure of the data coming from the AJAX call on the initial state and not just rely on it from the returned data itself ??

Original problem - I am trying to substring/slice a string that comes in through Ajax, but if it is not loaded, it will error as undefined, so I am trying to only apply it once it comes in.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cm7lbr

If I do not declare the original state (`state.name` as `''` in index.js), I will get `Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` because the data has not been loaded yet

Index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Parent from './Parent';
import './style.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      // Why does this have to be declared before it comes in through ajax
      name: '', 
      // list: []
      // otherAttrs: {}
    };
    this.bind()
  }

  updateList(args) {
    // Update state with harcoded list of items
    axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/unknown')
    .then(res => {
      const axData = res.data;
      this.setState({ 'data': axData.data });
      this.setState({ 'name': axData.data[4].name });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
      // always executed
    })  
  }

  bind() {
    this.updateList = this.updateList.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.updateList}>Click to complete AJAX Call</button>
        <Parent data={this.state.data} name={this.state.name}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App
```

Parent.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Childd from './Childd';

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  // Render parent component, pass items list and str 
  // into Childd's props
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        Parent... <br/><br/>
        <Childd data={this.props.data} name={this.props.name}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Parent
```

Childd.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Childd extends React.Component {
  // Redundant, but just putting this here
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  // Render Childd using this.props.str
  // React will handle the component's re-rendering
  // when state of Parent changes
  render () {
    //Tige
    return (
      <div>Childd... <br/>
        dataObj = … 
        <br/>
        Name attr: {this.props.name.slice(0,4).toUpperCase()}
        </div>     )
    }
}

export default Childd
```

Comment: Ajax request takes time to complete and it happens asynchronously. Before the response itself react components should be rendered. And if name is undefined, in the initial render it will throw undefined error.

Comment: Yes,   but why can I not just use `componentDidMount`, or some other approach, since `componentWill*` are getting deprecated, leaving me to believe those are not the correct approaches.  Or why does React not have builtin JS functions for data to be loaded/ or Ajax like helper functions, again, leaving me to believe there is something high level I am missing